# How are we meant to use IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<T>?

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I'm confused by the example in the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-claims-to-identity-using-iuserclaimsprincipalfactoryapplicationuser) that describes how to add claims using `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`.

The sample code shows how to extend the `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

...and then implement a `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` that tests that property to determine which claims to add:

```
if (user.IsAdmin)
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
}
else
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
}
```

It's not stated, but I think the implication is that something else (not shown) will set the `IsAdmin` property for a user in the database. I think they could have made that clear. (Also, it's disappointing that the example uses roles when there's so much confusion around roles versus claims, but I digress...)

Anyway, we have added some "role" claims to the user based on the value of that new `IsAdmin` property. So far, so good. What I don't understand is the next bit:

> The additional claim can then be used in the app. In a Razor Page, the `IAuthorizationService` instance can be used to access the claim value.

Sounds like the Razor page is going to access our claim then - but here's the code:

```
@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "IsAdmin")).Succeeded)
{
    ...
}
```

Is that *really* accessing the claim? It looks to me like it's accessing the `IsAdmin` property of the user instead. I don't see how the claim we added is referenced *at all* - unless there's something else that's not being explained.

That [overload of `AuthorizeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationserviceextensions.authorizeasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationServiceExtensions_AuthorizeAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_IAuthorizationService_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_System_String_) describes the last parameter as 'policyName'. Are we meant to assume that there's a policy called "IsAdmin" that checks for our new role claim?

What a terrible piece of documentation this is - and I'm ignoring the fact that it's [also in the wrong place](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18797).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's not stated, but I think the implication is that something else (not shown) will set the IsAdmin property for a user in the database.

You can set the IsAdmin where you want,For example you can set it when register.Here is a demo:
[image]

Input Model in register:

```
 public class InputModel
        {
            ...
            public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
        }
```

Post handler:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email ,IsAdmin=Input.IsAdmin};
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    //    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

> Is that really accessing the claim? It looks to me like it's accessing the IsAdmin property of the user instead. I don't see how the claim we added is referenced at all - unless there's something else that's not being explained.

> That overload of AuthorizeAsync describes the last parameter as 'policyName'. Are we meant to assume that there's a policy called "IsAdmin" that checks for our new role claim?

`IsAdmin` is a ploicy name in the code,you need to add a policy which name is `IsAdmin`,and check new role claim in it.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("role", "admin"));
            });
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty much as I figured, but there are far too many hidden assumptions for that documentation to be useful. If anything, I left more confused than when I arrived.

Comment: PS. I know it's just an example, but I'm amused by the idea that someone could *self-register* as an admin - what could go wrong? :-)